# make argument passing and multiple .PHONY targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, argument-passing

This Makefile .PHONY contains two targets: clean and cleanx. 
When I entered "make clean" or "make cleanx" worked fine. But, when I do "make" in the command line, it acts like "make clean". 
I expected that "make" should not do anything. There must be that I misunderstood. Would you explain what's going on and how to make "make" do nothing in this case?
BTW, This generic makefile takes any ~.c or ~.cpp files (w/o extension) and make them.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -x c -g -std=gnu99
# The following part of the makefile is generic. it can be used
# to build any executable just by changing the definition above
%: %.c
    @echo Making $@.c file
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $< 

%: %.cpp
    @echo "Making $@.cpp file"
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $< 

.PHONY: cleanx clean
cleanx: 
    rm -f *.exe *.o
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

Thanx in advance! 
(a debtor)<><

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make always runs the first explicit target defined in the makefile, unless you specify a particular target on the command line.

In this case, the first explicit target listed is `cleanx`, so that's what it will run if you give no arguments.

If you want it to run a different target by default, define that one first.

For example:

```
.PHONY: all
all:

.PHONY: cleanx clean
cleanx: 
        rm -f *.exe *.o
clean:
        rm -f *.o
```

Here since `all` has no prerequisites and is PHONY, it won't do anything.

Comment: It works. Thanks for your answer. I never thought about having two .PHONY's. (a debtor)<><

Comment: You can put `all` in the same `.PHONY` line as the others if you want, or make a different `.PHONY` line for each one.  It doesn't matter.